# Unable to scan location: /db/migration (unsupported protocol: resource) in spring boot (only native mode)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, native, flyway

I am using:
**Spring boot 3.1.2** and **flyway-core:9.21.0** in native image mode
When an application starts I am getting

> Unable to scan location: /db/migration (unsupported protocol:
> resource)

from

> org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner

Still, the migrations are scanned and applied successfully.

Could you please help to understand is this message is just an "artifact" and i can disregard this, or does it really affects functionality? And in case it's not affecting, how can i get rid of it?

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, and currently not going to be fixed.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31999